# Improper integral related to Gamma function

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, gamma-function

I found the following integral which seems an extension of the gamma function
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[1 -
\mathrm{e}^{-\left(\large ux^{a} + vx^{b}\right)}\right]
x^{-1 - c}\,\mathrm{d}x,
$$
where $u,v,a,b,c$ are all positive constant such that $c \in \left(0,1\right)$ and $a > b > c$.

In the case of $v = 0$, I evaluated the integral thanks to the change of variable $y = x^{a}$ in terms of the Gamma function, but, when both $u$ and $v$ are strictly positive, I can not make the exponent linear in $x$ when $a \ne b$. I also try to use the series representation of
$1 - \mathrm{e}^{-\left(ux^{a} + vx^{b}\right)}$ but it does not work. Do you have any suggestions or know some noteworthy extensions of the Gamma function that can help me?

Thanks a lot!

P.S.
I'm new to "mathematics", so I also appreciate suggestions on how to ask questions effectively here :)

Comment: Can we know where did you found this integral?

Comment: Sure @Pippo. I found the integral in probability theory. More precisely in the special case when $v=0$ and $a=1$ the integral, as function $u>0$, arises in the Laplace exponent of the marginal random variables of a stable process. This more general version arises as the two-dimensional extension (as function of $u >0$ and $v>0$) of the Laplace exponent of a modified stable process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration by parts results in a linear combination of two integrals of the form
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty x^{d-1}e^{-ux^a-vx^b}\,dx&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-v)^n}{n!}\int_0^\infty x^{bn+d-1}e^{-ux^a}\,dx\\&=\frac1{u^{d/a}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}\left(\frac{-v}{u^{b/a}}\right)^n\Gamma\left(\frac{bn+d}{a}\right).
\end{align*}
This series converges, but there's no general closed form for it (other than just a [name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function)).